# QT creator Installation error? - Snow Leopard

Tags: qt, installation, osx-snow-leopard

Does any one is having problems installing QT creator in snow leopard? 
I have been trying like 3 times, in different disk partitions and nothing works.

It freezes in "Validating packages..." then I got an error,

I am trying with Snow leopard 10.6.1 and QT 4.5 
I hope I can find some help here.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Let me google that for you](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/08/31/qt-46-on-mac-os-106/)

> *Full* Snow Leopard support will come with Qt 4.6. Until then, the official position is that Qt 4.5 is *not* supported on Snow Leopard.

Comment: I see... thanks!
Is there any night build or 4.6 beta or something I can use now?

Comment: There's a GIT repository you can look at: http://qt.gitorious.org/qt  but I doubt they fixed it yet.

Answer (score 3):

From: http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/08/31/qt-46-on-mac-os-106/

"I can confirm the above fix solves the install on Snow Leopard problem - where is hangs/fails when doing “Validating Packages” early in the install. To solve, first time you run installer uncheck the Qt Docs option under Customize - then re-run and install just the docs."

I'm using it on Snow Leopard without problems, Only one word of advice Qt 4.5.2 has a drawing issue on combos and context menus, to fix that you need to patch two files and rebuild Qt. Therefore maybe you can use the source distribution instead of the binary one, and download QtCreator separately.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I found a the way around it was to install each package individually.